# Storing averages of values in a dictionary in a separate dictionary - Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
scores = {'Ben': ['10', '9'], 'Alice': ['10', '10'], 'Tom': ['9', '8']}
```

I have calculated the average of the values for each person in the dictionary and I want to then store the averages in a separate dictionary. I would like it to look like this:

```
averages = {'Ben': [9.5], 'Alice': [10], 'Tom': [8.5]}
```

I have calculated the averages using this code:

```
for key, values in scores.items(): 
  avg = float(sum([int(i) for i in values])) / len(values)
  print(avg)
```

This gives the following output:

```
9.5
10.0
8.5
```

How can I output the averages in a separate dictionary as shown above?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
averages = {}    # Create a new empty dictionary to hold the averages
for key, values in scores.items(): 
  averages[key] = float(sum([int(i) for i in values])) / len(values)  
  # Rather than store the averages in a local variable, store them in under the appropriate key in your new dictionary.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use dict_comprehension.

```
>>> scores = {'Ben': ['10', '9'], 'Alice': ['10', '10'], 'Tom': ['9', '8']}
>>> {i:[float(sum(int(x) for x in scores[i]))/len(scores[i])] for i in scores}
{'Ben': [9.5], 'Alice': [10.0], 'Tom': [8.5]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary comprehension to loop over your items and calculate the proper result:

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> scores = {'Ben': ['10', '9'], 'Alice': ['10', '10'], 'Tom': ['9', '8']}
>>> scores = {k:[sum(map(int,v))/len(v)] for k,v in scores.items()}
>>> scores
{'Ben': [9.5], 'Alice': [10.0], 'Tom': [8.5]}
```

Note that you need to convert your values to `int` that you can do it with `map` function `map(int,v)`.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with a dict comprehension in one line:

```
averages = {k: sum(float(i) for i in v) / len(v) for k, v in scores.items() if v}
```